# Proving with mathematical induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

The question is:
Prove that  $$n+2(n-1)+3(n-2)+...+(n-2)3+(n-1)2+n = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$ for all integers $n≥1,$ by using mathematical induction.
I don't understand how to do any of it.
Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that
$n+2(n-1)+3(n-2)+...+(n-2)3+(n-1)2+n = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}
$.

First,
get rid of the
"..." by using summation notation.
The left side is
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(n-k+1)
$.
To check this,
the term for
$k=1$ is
$1\cdot n$
and the last term is
$n\cdot 1$.

So we want to show that
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(n-k+1)
= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}
$.

For $n=1$ this is
$1\cdot 1
=\frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3}{6}
$
which is true.

Now let's see how much
the two sides change
when you go from
$n$ to $n+1$.

The right side,
which is easier,
changes by
$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}
=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3-n)}{6}
=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(3)}{6}
=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$.

The left side changes by

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k(n-k+2)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(n-k+1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(n-k+2)+(n+1)(1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(n-k+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k(n-k+2)-k(n-k+1))+(n+1)(1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k(n-k+2-(n-k+1))+(n+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k+(n+1)\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)\\
&=\frac{n^2+n+2(n+1)}{2}\\
&=\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

This completes the proof,
because we have shown that
the two expressions
changes by the same amount
when they go from
$n$ to $n+1$
and they have the same value
at $n=1$.

There are a number of ways to
rearrange this proof,
and they would be
substantially equivalent.

To state this
in a more general way:

To show that
$f(n) = g(n)$,
first show that
$f(1) = g(1)$
and then show that
$f(n+1)-f(n)
=g(n+1)-g(n)
$.
Summing this last equality
gives a telescoping sum
on both sides
so that
$f(n+1)-f(1)
=g(n+1)-g(1)
$.
Since $f(1) = g(1)$,
this implies that
$f(n) = g(n)$
for all $n$.

Comment: You can rearrange it so it is a more standard proof. It would go like $f(1) = g(1)$ and $f(n+1)-f(n) = g(n+1)-g(n)$ plus the assumption that $f(n) = g(n)$ implies, by adding the last two equalities, that $f(n+1) = g(n+1)$. The key result needed is that $f(n+1)-f(n) = g(n+1)-g(n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed proof